# Is there a way to force next.js to let me use a regular image tag?

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

I have an Avatar component with an `<img>` tag. It's working fine in development mode, but when I try to build the project then Next.js throws the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./components/Avatar.js
59:9  Error: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element.  @next/next/no-img-element
```

I don't want to use the `next/image` module. It [doesn't work with blob images](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/19291). Is there a way to force next.js to let me use the regular `<img>` tag in production mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create `.eslintrc` (if you don't have it already) in project's root folder

Add the next code to turn off that lint check:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "@next/next/no-img-element": "off"
  }
}
```

This should solve your issue.

Learn more  -> [How To Disable ESLint Rules in NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules)